# Is there a way to do conditional parsing with python's struct.unpack?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to parse out a byte-oriented structure (GMTI dwell data in AEDP-7 format) where the presence of some of the fields is indicated by a 64-bit flag field at the start of the structure.

Because it works so well for earlier parts, I'd like to use Python's `struct` module to do the parsing. However I'd need to find a way to do conditional parsing based on the bits that are set in the flag field.

So far I have code that looks like this:

```
DWELL_SEGMENT_INITIAL_FORMAT = ">QHHBHIIII"
DWELL_SEGMENT_INITIAL_SIZE = struct.calcsize(DWELL_SEGMENT_INITIAL_FORMAT)

def unpackDwellSegmentData(segmentData):
    dwellSegment = struct.unpack(DWELL_SEGMENT_INITIAL_FORMAT, segmentData[0:DWELL_SEGMENT_INITIAL_SIZE])
    print(dwellSegment)
```

The next field (D10 - the tenth field in the dwell segment) is conditional, based on the value of byte 6 bit 7 in the bit mask. I could just switch to open coding the parsing logic based on the values in the bit mask, but would prefer not do that if there is a declarative way do handle this.

Is there a way to parse out this value (and the 39 following it) with `struct.unpack` declarative approach, and if so, what does it look like?

Comment: Did you try using `struct.unpack` to unpack the unconditional part, examining the result, and then using ordinary conditional logic (e.g. with `if` statements) to unpack the rest? I don't understand why there is a question. "The next field (D10 - the tenth field in the dwell segment) is conditional, based on the value of byte 6 bit 7 in the bit mask." - okay, but you know what that value is, because it's in the `dwellSegment` data.

Comment: My code already uses `struct.unpack` on the unconditional part - `DWELL_SEGMENT_INITIAL_FORMAT` - as shown in the question. I'd like to just pass all of the `segmentData` to struct.unpack and have it do the right thing, rather than do a partly declarative approach and a partly coded approach.

Comment: No, it doesn't support that - it's an unpacker, not a parser. If the goal is simply to avoid `if`, it could be done with a byte-regex, but "the complexity has to go somewhere" and that approach is not going to be pretty. Or you can try an actual parser such as with `pyparsing`, though performance will likely suffer. We don't really do recommendations, though, and the right tool would depend on your specific requirements.

Comment: You will need tow write a parser to unpack the various parts of the format. You may want to look at something like https://kaitai.io/ to help you write the parser in a declarative way.

Comment: There is [struct.unpack_from](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from) and [struct.iter_unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from) that can be helpful in unpacking file formats

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @ukBaz: Thanks, have already considered Kaitai Struct, and will likely give that a try next.